# ReactJS OnClick render

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I am trying to make a menu that by pressing any of the functions the active class will disappear and the new page will appear. In here for instance, I am trying to click on My Order and get forwarded to the page I asked to load. How do I make this correctly? Here is my current code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "./index.css";

class MainPanel extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-layout">
                <header>
                    <ul className="top">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                    </ul>
                </header>
                <ul className="categories">
                    <li>Main Panel</li>
                    <li onClick={<MyOrder />}>My Order</li>
                    <li>Technical Support</li>
                    <li>My Payments</li>
                    <li>Suggestions/ Questions</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
function MyOrder () {
        return (
            <div className="main-layout">
                <header>
                    <ul className="top">
                        <h1>My Order</h1>
                    </ul>
                </header>
                <ul className="categories">
                    <li>Where is my order?</li>
                    <li>My order delays more than the expected time</li>
                    <li>My order status shows that the order arrived but it did not</li>
                    <li>I have a complaint</li>
                    <li>Suggestions/ Questions</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <MainPanel />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: You may want to check out React Router.

Comment: Hey, I read about React Router but I do not want to change the URL when changing page, just render the page so user is basically on the same page and sees different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without React Router and other 3rd party libraries you could do something like this:

```
class Overview extends React.Component {
    onMenuClick(id) {
        return this.props.onMenuClick(id);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ul className="categories">
                <li onClick={this.onMenuClick.bind(this, "mainPanel")}>Main Panel</li>
                <li onClick={this.onMenuClick.bind(this, "myOrder")}>My Order</li>
                <li onClick={this.onMenuClick.bind(this, "technicalSupport")}>Technical Support</li>
                <li onClick={this.onMenuClick.bind(this, "myPayments")}>My Payments</li>
                <li onClick={this.onMenuClick.bind(this, "suggestions")}>Suggestions/ Questions</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

class MainPanel extends React.Component {
    // sets the initial value for this.state.page
    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            page: "overview"
        });
    }

    switchPage(id) {
        this.setState({ page: id });
    }

    showComponent() {
        if(this.state.page === "overview") return (<Overview
            onMenuClick={::this.switchPage}
        />);
        if(this.state.page === "myOrder") return <MyOrder />;

        throw new Error(`${this.state.page} is not a valid page id`);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="main-layout">
                <header>
                    <ul className="top">
                        <h1>Header</h1>
                    </ul>
                </header>
                { this.showComponent() }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

You change the view by updating the state. Depending on the state different components are mounted/unmounted.

Note based on my experience: Try to handle your app state (in our case the current page information) via React Baobab or something like this (centralized state) because otherwise all these props bubblings become confusing.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for helping. My code now leads to a blank page, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe you should throw an error at the end of showComponent: throw new Error(`${this.state.page} is not a valid page id`);

Comment: I think that you don't have an initial value for this.state.page. To set it use componentWillMount() { this.setState({ page: "overview" }) }

Comment: Hey, it now loads but won't work when clicking any of the categories I get an error. TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: That happens when this is not pointing to the MainPanel, but anywhere else. Did you use the :: notation? It's necessary here

Comment: I got an error for the :: so I removed it, but now when I put it back in place it says "unexpected token" and won't compile.